# Loop with VBA Vlookup, with dynamic cell value

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub tabelvul()

Dim nr(2)

For i = 2 To 31
    nr(1) = Range("AA" & i).Value
    nr(2) = Range("AN" & i).Value
    If nr(2) = 0 Then
        ' do nothing
    Else
        Range(nr(1)).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=VLOOKUP(nr(2),Tabel80[[Kolom1]:[Inschrijver]],2)"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

The first value `nr(1)` has is B4, so i do get the formula of Vlookup in B4, however he is searching for `nr(2)` and not the corresponding value of `nr(2)`, which is 1, so I want the formula to look for 1 in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there are other things that could be improved in your code, but you should change:

```
"=VLOOKUP(nr(2),Tabel80[[Kolom1]:[Inschrijver]],2)"
```

To this:

```
"=VLOOKUP(" & nr(2) & ",Tabel80[[Kolom1]:[Inschrijver]],2)"
```

Well it looks like you are wanting to enter the Vlookup on a range until nr(2) = Range("AN" & i).value = 0, so I don't know why you would use an array at all, if I knew what you were trying with more detail, could probably make it even better, but with what I know, this could do:

```
Sub tabelvul()
For i = 2 To 31
    If Range("AN" & i).Value = 0 Then
        ' do nothing
    Else
        Range("AA" & i).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=VLOOKUP(" & Range("AN" & i).Value & ",Tabel80[[Kolom1]:[Inschrijver]],2)"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou, I am really new to this so I can use every tip! what else would you change about the code?

Comment: @MilenavanderVelde Updated my answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: You could also make the loop from 2 to 31 dynamic, if it applies, do you only need it to go to 31? or are you trying to get the formula into the rows until the last row with data?

Comment: It only needs to go 31. Do you also have a tip for dynamic cell, so in my sheet I have tables who differ from size everytime. However I want to fill these headers and because everytime the header is in a different place, it is really hard to make a code to say where I have to place the header

Comment: Its quite hard to try to suggest something without having a look at how your data is laid out, if you can add a **sample** spreadsheet to something like Dropbox or Google Drive and add the link in your comments, then I will have a look at it, and try to make some suggestions for improvements...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should change `"=VLOOKUP(nr(2),Tabel80[[Kolom1]:[Inschrijver]],2)"` into `"=VLOOKUP(" & nr(2) & ",Tabel80[[Kolom1]:[Inschrijver]],2)"`